# Unknown length of input

Tags: c, string, fgets, getline

There are several ways how to retrieve string input, e.g `getline()` , or `fgets()` but all of them require size of the string as an argument. But what if i want to retrieve string of unknown size? How is it possible using `getline()` or `fgets()` in C?

Comment: `getline` is no standard C. As `fgets` **is** standard C, it would be strange if you could not use it. What is your problem? Please read [ask].

Comment: as i said , both of them requires size of the string as argument , i do not know the size of the string

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. You can't read a string of indeterminate length. You can, however, read one character at a time until you reach the size of the storage space you have allocated in your program. Use fgetc in a loop.

```
int fgetc(FILE *stream)
```

Open the stream , read one character at a time, and stop reading when you see your sentinel character, which is probably a newline.

Comment: You can read a string of indeterminate length. There’s just no builtin to do it.

Comment: Well, you can do anything at all, there's just no builtin to do it.

Comment: (The reason I bring it up is that in “You can't read a string of indeterminate length. You can, however, read one character at a time until you reach the size of the storage space you have allocated in your program.”, the “other” option isn’t built-in either.)

Comment: My answer describes exactly what you are saying, but technically it's not reading a string, it's reading a series of char items and saving them contiguously.